# Ubuntu 17.10 mouse stick

Tags: mouse

I have an Acer aspire es1-711. I just upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 and now my mouse keeps freezing. it is a generic wireless mouse with fresh batteries put in. I am a complete noob with Ubuntu and need detailed instruction. My computer has 8 gigs ram, and the main hard drive is 500 gigs. Thank you.

Comment: These are two (probably separate) problems that should be asked as separate questions.  Please update your question to include the output of `lspci -knn | grep net -a3` so that we can have a little more information about your wifi system

Comment: My wireless was fixed by my provider.

Comment: I have since re-installed the operating system and everything seems to be working fine.  So my issue has been solved.